# 301 Redirect not working on particular URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a redirect rule set up as below

```
Redirect /Products.aspx?Category_ID=15 https://www.trainerbubble.com/free-training-resources/
```

However, when going to the address it attaches itself to an existing page /training-products and results in this

```
https://www.trainerbubble.com/training-products/?Category_ID=15
```

How can I force the original redirect and make it stop thinking its part of the /training-products page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match query string in `Redirect` directive. Use `mod_rewrite` rules instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Category_ID=15$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^Products\.aspx$ https://www.trainerbubble.com/free-training-resources/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`?` at the end of target URL is to strip off previous query string.